# Prevent specific Mirrors from being used in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, kali-linux, apt-mirror

I am using the official Kali mirror which is `http.kali.org`. Which redirects to other best mirrors during package installation.

```bsh
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# Additional line for source packages
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

But, the problem is there are some lazy mirrors. Two of them are http://ftp.free.fr/pub/kali and http://archive-4.kali.org/kali. They're super slow but often chosen. They grab in 100-150 kBps where others grab in 1300+ kBps. While installing large packages it takes so long that I need immediately.

I want to never use these two mirrors while installation. Is there any way I can prevent these mirrors from being used when using the official(http.kali.org) mirror?

Comment: find the closest, fastest mirror and use that.

Comment: @cas I've changed it previous time and I've faced some package management problems. Eventually, entire distro broke. I had no know but reinstall it losing all my datas.

Comment: if the "entire distro broke" then that's because of something you did, not because one of the mirrors was slow to update or whatever (so don't just accept whatever apt/apt-get proposes to do - check whether it wants to remove any packages that you need and **decide for yourself** whether you want to accept that removal).    Use your fastest, closest mirror by default.  Switch to using http.kali.org if that mirror is behind and you're too impatient to wait a day or so.